# how to install adobe air sdk in linux?

Tags: linux, sdk, installation, air

i'm trying to install the adobe air sdk in linux. i unzip the package downloaded from http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tools/sdk/ into a folder "AdobeAIRSDK", and add the /bin folder into the PATH environment variable. but when i tried to run the adl, it gives me the following error:

Error loading the runtime (/home/monuser/AdobeAIRSDK/bin/../runtimes/air/linux/Adobe AIR/Versions/1.0/Resources/nss3/None/libnss3.so: file too short)

what's the problem here and how do i get it fixed?

Comment: as a note, the adt works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to install on a 64-bit OS? Either way, [Adobe has a KB](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/408/kb408084.html) on installation that might help.

Answer (score 3):

```
Installing Adobe Air on Ubuntu 13.10
```

Install i386 libraries, that are required for successful installation and running of Adobe Air and air applications:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 lib32nss-mdns libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386    
Install gnome-keyring:i386.
```

It can't be installed using apt-get as other i386 (at least at the moment of writing this), because of it's dependencies. So we'll need to download it and install manually. In fact, this is easy:

download deb-package using apt-get to /tmp:

```
cd /tmp

sudo apt-get download libgnome-keyring0:i386
```

extract deb-package into gnome-keyring subfolder (note version in the file name, it may be different):

```
sudo dpkg-deb -R libgnome-keyring0_3.8.0-2_i386.deb gnome-keyring
```

install library in the system by copying:

```
sudo cp gnome-keyring/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
```

create symlinks so Adobe Air could see it:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
```

Download Adobe Air installer from Adobe official site: `http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html`

Install Adobe Air using downloaded installer (don't forget to allow execution of the installer file):

```
chmod a+x AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
sudo ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
```

Adobe Air should be installed successfully now! Now you may remove excess symlinks:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
sudo rm /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
```

[Source](http://www.tkalin.com/blog_posts/installing-adobe-air-and-elance-tracker-on-ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander-64-bit)

Comment: Do you know where the installation is placed ?

Comment: @Simeon: Hopefully in `/var/opt/Adobe AIR`. As it has further issues with latest jQuery. So I could not work with it in ubuntu. Since I uninstalled that and using Windows 8 for Air Client only.